# Titanium Appcelerator orientationchange doesn't occur

Tags: android, appcelerator, orientation-changes

I have a problem with `orientationchange` in titanium appcelerator. When moving between tabs, the `orientationchange` event is not fired when switching between portrait & landscape.

Here's my code

```
Titanium.Gesture.addEventListener('orientationchange', function(e){

    var alertDialog = Ti.UI.createAlertDialog({
        title: "Alert",
        message: "Orientation is "+  e.orientation,
        buttonNames: ['OK'],
        cancel:0
    });
    alertDialog.show();

});
```

Here's the reproduction steps:

1. Switch to tab 2, and then enter landscape mode(alert appears).
2. Switch back to tab 1, rotate phone into portrait mode(alert doesn't appear).
3. The event does not occur. (Subsequent events fire as usual(alert appears))

Anyone have an idea on a work-around?
I need that because I have to change view `onorientationchange`.
I'm using Titanium Appcelerator 1.2.2, mobile version 1.6, Api 2.2

Answer (score 0):

*nevermind*

EDIT: I found a workaround http://developer.appcelerator.com/question/74781/orientationchange-is-never-fired

Comment: I have tried but alert doesn't appear. The problem isn't orientationchange never fire but orientationchange doesn't fire in this kind of context: Here's the reproduction steps:

   1. Switch to tab 2, and then enter landscape mode(alert appears).
   2. Switch back to tab 1, rotate phone into portrait mode(alert doesn't appear).
   3. The event does not occur. (Subsequent events fire as usual(alert appears))
aniway thank you

Answer (score 0):

```
Ti.Gesture.addEventListener('orientationchange', function(e){

var alertDialog = Ti.UI.createAlertDialog({ 
    title: "Alert", message: "Orientation is "+ e.orientation, buttonNames: ['OK'], cancel:0 }); alertDialog.show();

});
```